# Django showing 'It Worked' page 50% of the time

Tags: django, lighttpd

I set up URLs in my urls.py file in my main project, like so:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',gamelog.views.frontpage,name='home'),
    url(r'^user/register/',gamelog.views.register,name='register'),
)
```

Problem is, about 50% of the time when I visit the homepage, I'll get the 'It Worked' page, and the other 50% is the actual view I designated.
However, if I visit /user/register, 50% of the time is the 'It Worked' page, and the other 50% is a 404 that says:

```
Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^/?$
The current URL, user/register, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache etc.?

Comment: Yes, and wouldn't it be a constant view of the 'It worked!' page if it was cached? And not show my dynamic data?

Comment: If by dynamic you mean something that you changed after you added the `register` URL, you're right of course. Apart from that my experience tells me that you cannot really tell what caches do, so a 50% "hit" rate would seem reasonable.

Comment: Solved my issue, it's odd, but it makes sense that there'd be unpredictable behaviour, if you look at my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, embarrassingly enough, I was restarting lighttpd to make the app work again, not the actual FCGI socket (e.g. FLUP).

So, the solution is to restart the PYTHON server, not the webserver.
I feel like an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

You are visiting `user/register`, when your url is `user/register/`

Did you remove [`CommonMiddleware`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware) from your settings? It should redirect correctly to the URL with the `/` if its a valid pattern.

Comment: CommonMiddleware is on, both user/register and user/register/ fail. Good thinking though.

Comment: 404 again. The 'more detail' bit seems to suggest there's only one url - ^/?$

Comment: Upvoted, because you had helpful information. I did answer my own question, however.